# How to write read and save in php

Tags: php, html

so I'm making a project, but there is a little problem (button doesn't work in php) this is my code, what's wrong? it can read but can't write
this is my setting.php

```html
<?php error_reporting(0);
include '../anjayalok.php'; 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="col-lg-6"> <label class="form-label" for="mail2">Ressult</label><input class="form-control" id="mail_2" type="text" value="<?= $result; ?>" /></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"> <label class="form-label" for="email1">Sender</label><input class="form-control" id="param1" type="text" value="<?= $sender; ?>" /></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"> <label class="form-label" for="email2">style</label><input class="form-control" id="Param2" type="text" value="<?= $style; ?>" /></div>
<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end"><?php echo $setting;?><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update </button></div></form>
</html>
```

and is my anjayalok.php

```html
<?php error_reporting(0);
$setting = array(
'ressult' => 'ex@example.com',
'sender' => 'ex',
'style' => 'ex',
$result = $setting['ressult']; 
$sender = $setting['parameter']; 
$style = $setting['style'];
);
```

Comment: Not sure where you are going with this, if you are using the form you need to add names to your inputs and use $_POST in php to get the values.

Comment: I don’t know what your problem is, but `error_reporting(0)` disables error reporting which is never a good thing when debugging

Comment: Give more clarification please